Alpine can't access variable set with data()
I'm using Astro with the Alpine integration, rendering set to static.
I am trying to fetch data and based on the response render some html client side.
stats.ts
const FUNCTIONS_BASE_URL = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_AZURE_FUNCTIONS

interface Statistic {
    metrics: number[];
    dimensions: string[];
}

export interface GlobalMetrics {
    statistics: Statistic[];
}

export const getStatistics = async (): Promise<GlobalMetrics> => {
    const response = await fetch(
        `${FUNCTIONS_BASE_URL}/api/stats`
    );
    const data: Statistic[] = await response.json();

    return { statistics: data }
}

Astro page
---
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
---

<script>
    import { getStatistics } from "../scripts/stats";
    import type { GlobalMetrics } from "../scripts/stats";
    const statistics = await getStatistics();

    document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
        window.Alpine.data("stats", () => ({
            metrics: statistics as GlobalMetrics,
            async init() {
                console.log(this.metrics);
            },
        }));
    });
</script>

<Layout>
    <div x-data="stats"></div>
</Layout>

This results in ReferenceError: stats is not defined

What line of code is that error coming from? Is alpine:init ever fired?
btw. I assume there is a good reason you want to use Alpine instead of vanilla javascript or just rendering the statistics on the server?

Yes, my app is a static site. I ended up fixing the issue by just using normal Alpine js and not the Astro integration.

I'm not sure what the error was, if anyone knows why this occurs I will gladly accept that as an answer.
This error seesm to stem from the way Astro bundles javascript. I removed @astrojs/alpinejs and just installed alpinejs and import it in my script tag like so;
<script>
    import Alpine from "alpinejs";

    window.Alpine = Alpine;
    Alpine.data("stats", () => ({
    }));

    Alpine.start();
</script>

Which works great.
